# Ember - Use View Click event to trigger click of File Input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I want to handle the click event of a View and trigger a click on a file input element.

I also don't want to show the 'ugly' input element box, so I have used CSS to push it off viewport and set opacity to 0.

```
input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I did a mockup in HTML with jQuery, and it works exactly as I want. Refer link: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H7kvP/)**

I also tried to implement the same in Ember, and it is throwing an error of

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

FYI, here is the Ember - **[JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/giqunoya/1/)**

```
// View
App.DropView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'dropView',

  click: function(event) {

    $("input[type='file']").click();
    event.preventDefault();

  }
});
```

Template:

```
<!-- Template -->
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='dropView'>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Click Me</a>
    <input type='file' id='files'>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the event propagation on the input or else triggering the click on the input will keep triggering the click on the view :

http://jsbin.com/giqunoya/4/

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I read that I need to stop the propagation of event, but wasn't sure on where to add that hook.

Comment: Glad I could help, the didInsertElement hook will often save your life :)

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the click event to the entire view.
So when you click the `<a>` tag, this is what's happening:

- The event will bubble up to the view
- The click on the view is called
- The file input is clicked
- The event will bubble up to the view
- repeat until `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

You should only bind the click event on the `<a>` tag,

```
App.DropView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'dropView',

  didInsertElement:function(){  
    this.$('a').click(function(){
       Ember.$("input[type='file'").click();
    });               
  },

  willDestroyElement:function(){
    this.$('a').off();
  }  
});
```